# How to tell if a form checkbox is checked through a pageload asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, pageload

Sorry if this is a duplicate, most of the questions that I looked at were similar but not the same question.

I have a form with a checkbox:

`<input id = "ppCheckBox" type = "checkbox" name = "policy"/>`

I do an ajax call in my JS to send all form data to a page load. I want to be able to know if that checkbox is checked during page load.

Any ideas on how to do this? is there something like `Request.Params.["policy"].isChecked()`? Or any method that I can use just to determine if it is checked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added your input and an asp button to a page, clicked the button, and viewed the `Request["policy"]` in the debugger.

When the checkbox is unchecked, `Request["policy"]` returns `null`.  When it's checked, it returns `"on"`.

Answer (score 2):

Make it server side:

```
<input runat="server" id = "ppCheckBox" type = "checkbox" name = "policy"/>
```

Then you can reference `ppCheckBox` by name in your C# code.